# How to SELECT the difference of two columns from two different tables and calculate percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I need to list four columns in my final result. The revenue, cost, profit, and the profit as percentage of revenue. I already SELECT the revenue and cost from two different tables and INNER JOIN them, so how can I calculate the profit (revenue minus cost), and the profit as percentage of revenue (divide profit by revenue).
I am assuming the code should looks like this?

```
SELECT
  t.revenue,
  s.cost,
  (SELECT t.revenue minus SELECT s.cost) "profit", (("profit"/t.revenue)*100.00) AS "Q%"
FROM t
INNER JOIN s
ON t.store = s.store
```

Is that correct?

Comment: First rewrite `SELECT t.revenue minus SELECT s.cost` as `t.revenue-s.cost`

Comment: Pls remove the irrelevant product tags!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. But almost good :-)

```
SELECT t.revenue
,      s.cost
,      t.revenue - s.cost   "profit"
,      ((t.revenue - s.cost)/t.revenue)*100.00 AS "Q%"
FROM t
INNER JOIN s
ON t.store = s.store
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both "Inner Join" or "Where" clause for this query:

> Using Where Clause

```
SELECT t.revenue, s.cost, (t.revenue - s.cost) AS profit,
        (((t.revenue - s.cost)/t.revenue)*100.00) AS "Q%"
FROM t, s
where t.store = s.store
```

> Using Inner Join

```
SELECT t.revenue, s.cost, (t.revenue - s.cost) AS profit,
        (((t.revenue - s.cost)/t.revenue)*100.00) AS "Q%"
FROM t
INNER JOIN s
ON t.store = s.store
```